# prevent users for using certain characters in a calculator

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

i'm making a calculator and i want to throw a window with a message saying that only numbers are accepted in case that the user types a character which isn't a number in the textField, so this is what i did and didn't work at all.
Thanks for reading.

```
private void txtPantallaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String invalids;
    invalids = "|@#¢∞¬÷“”≠´‚πø  ¥†®€æœå∫∂ƒ™¶§ ~–…„µ ß√©∑Ωqwertyuiopñlkjhgfdsazxcvbnm!$%&/=?¿*^QWERTYUIOPÑLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < invalids.length() ; i++)
    {
        if(txtPantalla.getText().equals (invalids.substring(i, i+1)))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Only works with numbers");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Why not just eat the key press, that should send the message well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for readability and to avoid loop:

```
String value = txtPantalla.getText();
if(Pattern.matches(".*[^0-9].*", value)) {
  // there are some invalid characters!
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only works with numbers");
}
```

Any solution that requires you to hardcode something is probably wrong.